# Как закидывать проекты на GitHub при помощи AIDE

Tags: github, aide

У меня есть *AIDE* полная версия (Premium-key). В нем есть возможность работы с git, только вот я никак понять не могу, как закидывать проекты на GitHub? В интернете нет ни одного туториала по этому вопросу... Можете описать подробно, как коммитить проект на GitHub'e через AIDE?

Answer (score 1):

Прямо на сайте у AIDE есть подробный [мануал](http://www.android-ide.com/tutorial_git.html). Более того, там даже с гитхабом пример.

Comment: Что-то там не так с мануалом. К примеру, у меня нет чекбокса "Create new Git repository", а в файлах только пункт "Clone Git repository", хотя в мануале написано просто "Git".

Comment: А... Нашёл эту кнопку в настройках. Только вот я нажимаю "Push", но на гитхабе ничего не появляется..

Comment: У меня нет AIDE, тем более платной версии. Поэтому, я не могу проверить, есть там такая галочка или нет и почему оно не работает. Но у Вас же платный ключик - напишите [им](http://www.android-ide.com/about.html).